# Selecting specific columns from a dataTable and copy it to another DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a DataTable Dt1 and another DataTable Dt2.

Dt1 contains many columns and rows and Dt2 is basically empty

I know I should use Dt1.Select to select the specific DataTaRow [] but how can I copy them to Dt2

```
DataRow [] row = Dt1.Select("ID,MIN_VALUE,MAX_VALUE");
```

how can i copy them to Dt2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For .Net Framework 3.5+*

You can use [`CopyToDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

> Returns a DataTable that contains copies of the DataRow objects, given
>   an input IEnumerable object.

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("Your string");
DataTable dt2 = dr.CopyToDataTable();
```